# I cant figure out a inner join in this case

Tags: sql, oracle

1. I have a table called as A that has a primary key A_ID
2. I have a second table called as B that has a primary key B_ID and foreign key A_ID
3. I have a third table called C that has a primary key C_ID and foreign key B_ID and a row called as names.

For my case lets assume table A has ID's 1-10 B has ID's 10-100 and c has ID's 100-1000

Now I want the following functionality: I want all names from table C that has B_ID which is has a foreign key A_ID=3

So basically lets say some names in table C would have B_ID 20,30,40,50,60 and in table B B-ID 20 and 30 have A-ID 3

So I want data from table C that has only B_ID's 20 and 30

I hope I was clear enough, I would have mentioned the query that I wrote but I dont want the reader to get confused any more.

Thanks in advance............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT C.names
FROM C
    INNER JOIN B ON C.B_ID = B.B_ID
    INNER JOIN A ON B.A_ID = A.A_ID
WHERE A.A_ID = 3
```

Comment: It is executing properly but I think I am not getting any data which I am sure I am supposed to. May be I will put some test data and see. Wait. But anyways looks good to me.. Thanks a lot.. Appreciate the help..

Comment: If there is no data pulling back, then there are no records in B that have A_ID = 3 OR there are no records in C that has a B_ID that points to A_ID = 3. See sqlfiddle of it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b67ba/3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something but if all you want is data from table c based on information available in that table you don't need to join to other table unless you want to verify `B_ID` is present in `table b`

```
Select * from TableC where B_ID in (20,30)
```

Edit:
here is entire join that will return all rows from table `C` where `B

```
SELECT C.*
    FROM A
    JOIN B
        ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID
        AND B.B_ID IN (20,30)
    JOIN C
        ON B.B_ID = C.B_ID
    WHERE A.A_ID = 3
```

Comment: In the above example it is ok that you wrote (20,30). what if I have thousands of records.

Comment: I wrote that based on your statement `So I want data from table C that has only B_ID's 20 and 30`

Comment: that was an example sir